# Nuxt 3 to firebase MIME Error expected module

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, nuxt.js, nuxt3

My nuxt 3 app runs fine locally but when I deploy it to firebase using nuxt build and firebase deploy it returns the following error:

> Failed to load module script:
> Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a
> MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for
> module scripts per HTML spec.

firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": { "source": ".output/server", "runtime": "nodejs18" },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "my-app-54d17",
      "public": ".output/public",
      "cleanUrls": true,
      "rewrites": [{ "source": "**", "function": "server","region": "europe-west2" }]
    }
  ]
}
```

nuxt.config.ts

```
export default{
 css: ['@/assets/main.css'],
   nitro: {
    preset: 'firebase',
    replace: {
      [`functions.https.onRequest`]: `functions.region('europe-west2').https.onRequest`,
    }
}
}
```

What could be causing this error and how do I get a more detailed error log/stack trace?